# Bootstrap select with search not working in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap select search is not working.May be there is small thing i am missing.
I have using bootstrap select which is working fine.Select options coming from database.added data-live-search="true" for search which is not working.Select dropdown not opening.

Code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<?php $sql = "select * from vehicle order by vehiclename";
$vehicle_list = $mysqli->query($sql);

$schematron_array['Level5'] == coming from different table ?>

<label>Vehicle</label>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="vehicle">
    <option value="">Select vehicle</option>
    <?php while( $row = $vehicle_list->fetch_array() ) { 
        if(!empty($row['vehiclename'])) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['vehiclename']; ?>" <?php echo ($schematron_array['Level5'] == $row['vehiclename'])?"selected":""; ?> >
        <?php echo $row['vehiclename']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

Thanks.
Please Forgive if any mistake is there.

Comment: are you using Select2 ?

Comment: No.just using select.same as shows in the above code

Comment: use select2 for search select with search its quite easy.https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: I have studied Select2 and its great.It makes me lot more easier to search and multi-select.Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two issues -
1. jQuery is missing.
2. Database not returning any rows.

I used your code, applied jQuery and supplied some hard-coded values and it is working fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<label>Vehicle</label>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="vehicle">
    <option value="">Select vehicle</option>
    <option value="">Vehicle 1</option>
    <option value="">Vehicle 2</option>
    <option value="">Vehicle 3</option>
    <option value="">Vehicle 4</option>
    <option value="">Vehicle 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My mistake.I had put old version of jquery.Its working now.

Comment: Happy to help :)